How to make a rounded header where the logo is
I'm trying to make the header rounder and extend down where the logo is.
At the moment I'm using a pseudo element on the a tag which contains the logo with a white background and a border-radius.
I'd like to have have it more like in the image attached below, with the header flowing more fluid from the left, under the logo and then to the right.
ChatGPT suggested using clip path but every example it gave didn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Example of what I would like:


Pretty picture, but unless you show us your html and css, there is no way we can guess at how to help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://css-shape.com/inner-curve/

How do you want the header to behave on different viewport widths? Do you want the rounded extension under the logo to remain a constant size and stay in position as you stretch the viewport horizontally, or do you want it to move and stretch proportionally?
I assume you would want the extension to remain a constant size and stay in position. The simplest way to do this is to use a background-image. Create an image that looks like this, only make it white-and-transparent instead of black-and-transparent.



body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/791/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 100px 30px 160px;
  background-image: url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-79146597.webp);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header img {
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

header nav a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
<header>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/240">
  <nav>
    <a href="">Menu 1</a>
    <a href="">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="">Menu 3</a>
  </nav>

</header>




Exactly what i needed. I created an image with the exact shape i wanted and used that instead of the white background and border radius i had before.
I added a few media queries to position it perfectly. On mobile the logo is centered so that round thing is also centered.
Thank you!
